# how to get text area value in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, textarea

i am trying to send the value of text area into database but i am unable to get the values of text area. and also i want once data is saved to database i want to show that data in text area. kindly help me.

Thanks. 
here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function save()
{
var mail = {
                aboutus: $('textarea#area1').val(),
                services: $("#area2").val(),
                contact: $("#area3").val()

              };
        $.ajax({
                url: "user_stall_add.php",
                type: "POST",
                enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                data: mail,

                success: function(data) {

alert("Content Added");



                }
            });
            }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>

<h4 style="margin-left:4em;">About Us Content</h4>
<textarea name="area1" id="area1"  style="margin-left:4em;" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>

<input type="button" style="margin-left:4em;" value="Save" onclick="save();"><br />

<h4 style="margin-left:4em;">Services Content</h4>
<textarea  name="area2" id="area2"  cols="60" rows="10">
Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
<input type="button" style="margin-left:4em;" value="Save" onclick="save();"><br />

<h4 style="margin-left:4em;">Contact Content</h4>
<textarea style="margin-left:4em;" id="area3" name="area3" cols="60" rows="10">
HTML <b>content</b> <i>default</i> in textarea
</textarea>
<input style="margin-left:4em;" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();"><br />
</div>
```

Comment: `.val()` should work. Why do you think it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `nicEditors`,

```
          var aboutus  = new nicEditors.findEditor('area1').getContent();            
          var services  = new nicEditors.findEditor('area2').getContent();             
          var contact  = new nicEditors.findEditor('area3').getContent();

          var mail = {
            aboutus: aboutus,
            services: services,
            contact: contact

          };
```

REF: http://nicedit.com/demos.php

Doc: http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API

Returns the current HTML of the nicInstance

For example:

```
nicEditors.findEditor('myArea2').getContent();
```

returns the HTML in the content editor that replaced the element on the page with ID 'myArea2'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `$('#area1').val()` to match your other textarea(s). Also, make sure there is a value in the textarea - or you'll get an undefined. Finally, your sample works fine when I just use

```
function test() {
  // These both work for me.
  console.log($("textarea#area1").val());
  console.log($('#area1').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
         aboutus: $('textarea#area1').val(),
        services: $('textarea#area2').val(),
         contact: $('textarea#area3').val()
```